# How do base internal formats work?

Tags: opengl, textures

The [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) function accepts, among others, the so-called "base internal formats" listed below:

```
GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT
GL_DEPTH_STENCIL
GL_RED
GL_RG
GL_RGB
GL_RGB
```

These appear to lack any type or size information. Quoting the documentation:

> If an application wants to store the texture at a certain resolution or in a certain format, it can request the resolution and format with internalFormat. The GL will choose an internal representation that closely approximates that requested by internalFormat, but it may not match exactly. (The representations specified by `GL_RED`, `GL_RG`, `GL_RGB`, and `GL_RGBA` must match exactly.)

These formats are not listed in the documentation for [`glTexStorage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml), and I cannot find anything more precise about them. I've apparently made `GL_RGBA` work by dumb luck, but I would like to understand better what I'm doing here.

What exactly happens when I use a base internal format?
How are the type, size and layout of storage chosen?
Am I expected to query the chosen format afterwards and adjust the rest of my program, such as GLSL sampler types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `glTexStorage*` doesn't allow "base internal formats" is because you *should not* be using them. It only supports internal formats with well-defined behavior.

> What exactly happens when I use a base internal format?

You get an image format that is whatever the driver wants to give you, within the limits listed below.

> How are the type, size and layout of storage chosen?

The "type" will for such textures always be unsigned, normalized integers. It will have at least the channels in the base internal format.

Everything else is entirely up to the driver. If the driver wants to add more channels than you specified, it can do so. If the driver wants to give you a 16-bit-per-channel format, it can do so.

> Am I expected to query the chosen format afterwards and adjust the rest of my program, such as GLSL sampler types?

There's nothing to query, since they're always unsigned, normalized images. So you use `sampler*`, not `usampler*` or `isampler*` in shaders.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, I'm better off staying away from these formats at all times, right?

Comment: @Quentin Not the answerer, but yes, you should in general stay away from these formats, because internally they do conversions that aren't necessarily quick (sometimes even on the CPU!) and they probably don't do what you expect.  For example, you might have data that is stored on the CPU as 3 byte RGB pixels in an image.  First, the device you're using probably doesn't *actually* have a RGB format, so when you use base internal formats for GL_RGB it actually turns into a manual transition into normalized RGBA.  Then it does this on the *CPU* before being uploaded to the GPU.

Comment: @Quentin the right thing to do in that scenario is a manual expansion into a properly supported device format, you save 25% on bandwidth with this method as well!